# Display a value dependent on picklist value and last modified

Tags: formula

I am trying to create a formula that is based off of the stage, and when it was last modified.  The criteria are as follows:

1. If Stage = Submitted and Date Submitted and Date Last Modified are the Same, Value = New
2. If Stage = Submitted and Date Submitted and Date Last Modified are NOT the Same, Value = Revised
3. If Stage = Withdrawn and Date Submitted and Date Last Modified are the Same, Value = Null
4. If Stage = Withdrawn and Date Submitted and Date Last Modified are NOT the Same, Value = Withdrawn

Also, if anyone knows of a template or helpful way to create formulas, I would love to figure out a way to figure this out on my own.  :-)

Comment: What do you have so far? I would suggest taking a look at these links and see what you can come up with.https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=useful_advanced_formulas.htm&language=en_US and https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_examples_dates.htm&language=en_US then update your question with you formula for feedback.

Comment: Can I also suggest that using "last modified" as a comparison criteria may not be the best idea, since SO many things can change a Last Modified Date, without actually impacting field that are legitimately tied to this comparison.